# How can I get my app.iml to stay stable on Android Studio project rebuild?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

The order of the orderEntry library tags in my app.iml keeps changing when I switch branches and Android Studio rebuilds my project.  Is there any way to get Android Studio to generate it in a stable/deterministic way so that I don't constantly have diffs in git where a library moved up or down in the order?

Sometimes it's like this:

```
<orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="support-annotations-21.0.3" level="project" />
<orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="google-http-client-jackson2-1.19.0" level="project" />
```

Other times it's like this:

```
<orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="google-http-client-jackson2-1.19.0" level="project" />
<orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="support-annotations-21.0.3" level="project" />
```

I don't really care I just want it to stop churning.

**Edit**:

According to JetBrains you are supposed to share the .iml files:

http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23393067

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add this files to gitignore:

```
*.iml
```

Comment: According to JetBrains you are supposed to share the .iml files:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23393067

Comment: @kg. First line is: 'If you decide to share IDE project files with other developers, follow these guidelines'. So you can decide not to share. It doesn't mean that you should to do it. As i understand it. Please check this resource https://www.gitignore.io/ gitignores can be not perfect but very useful.

Comment: It looks like you're right.  Supposedly the comments on that page don't apply if you're building completely from Gradle (which is confusing because he mentions Gradle, but oh well).